# Unable to delete a folder from a shared Google-Drive space, using Drive API, even though I am the owner of the folder

Tags: python-3.x, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to create a python script that will delete/trash/remove the contents of a folder located on a google shared drive with the following code:

```
    Drive = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    def deleteWorkspace():
        principles = Drive.files().list(q="'%s' in parents and not trashed"%(ROOT_FOLDER_ID)).execute().get('files')
        if len(principles)>0:
            for p in principles:
                print(p['name'])
                Drive.files().delete(fileId = p['id'],supportsAllDrives=True)
```

The script runs to completion without any errors however, the folder in question, and its contents remain present on the shared drive space.

I find this to be particularly strange as I am the owner of the folder in question and all similar issues to mine have seemingly been resolved by utilizing the owners' credentials.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete?hl=en#response

When utilizing the link above along with the corresponding `fileId` String for `p['id']`, the folder and its contents are successfully removed from the shared drive space.

Any advice/suggestions as to why my script is not achieving the same results as described when using the above link would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try adding execute() at the end of the command so it gets run.

```
Drive.files().delete(fileId = p['id'],supportsAllDrives=True).execute()
```

Comment: Oh, wow, that's embarrassing xD Thanks so much, worked like a charm! I really thought there was more to this issue than just oversight.